# LocalDate to fetch last week saturday date

Tags: java, datetime, java-8

My problem statement - 
My date looks like this = `LocalDate - 20180923`

I need to write a function which takes 3 inputs - 
date (2018-09-23), 
offset (1) => means we need to find last saturday for last week, 
day (SATURDAY) => means we need to find for saturday.

So, In this case if i call my function `getLastWeekDateForDay("20180923", 1, "SATURDAY")` => this should return me string `"20180922"`

Another example - 
`getLastWeekDateForDay("20180923", 2, "FRIDAY") => "20180914"`

I do not know how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For something like this, you use [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html), like this:

```
public static String getLastWeekDateForDay(String date, int offset, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek) {
    return LocalDate.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE)
                    .with(TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame(dayOfWeek))
                    .minusWeeks(offset)
                    .format(DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE);
}
```

If the `dayOfWeek` is a `String`, use [`DayOfWeek.valueOf(String name)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-).

*Test*

```
System.out.println(getLastWeekDateForDay("20180923", 1, DayOfWeek.SATURDAY));
System.out.println(getLastWeekDateForDay("20180923", 2, DayOfWeek.FRIDAY));
```

*Output*

```
20180922
20180914
```

Comment: You can use a constant instead of defining your formatting pattern: [`DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#BASIC_ISO_DATE). And turn your method into a one-liner: `LocalDate.parse( date, DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE ).with( TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame( dayOfWeek) ).minusWeeks( offset ).format( DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE )`